# Can i remove starforce?

Tags: 12.04, wine, drm

I installed TM Nation ESWC wity Wine-install want successful.
but when running and presing "play" i got this:

[image]

thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

StarForce uses its own drivers for direct I/O to the disc-drive as part of
its anti disc-emulation DRM, its drivers are also used to prevent its code
being run under any emulator to prevent reverse engineering.

Its unlikey that wine will support this, i would suggest you search the game
publishers site for a patch which may have a DRM free executable or a less
stronger implementation of SF on it.